# RPC Ports getting reset to 5000-5002 on reboot

Tags: active-directory, domain, port, rpc, endpoint

I've run into a very common issue with RPC Endpoint Mapper ports not being available. The default RPC ports are 5000-5002. When I edit the registry and set the ports to a wider range (say, xx100 - xx500 ) and reboot, it seems to work.

Funny thing is, upon reboot, the ports get reset to 5000-5002. So the increased number of ports work for 1 reboot only.

What could be the reason behind the RPC ports going back to the original values?

Comment: The default ports are 5000-5002? What? Where did you get this range? Sounds like you are battling a group policy preference somewhere

Comment: That's what I'm wondering as well. Just 2 open ports is causing severe impediments to normal functioning of RPC. Strangely, when I do a search for GPOs that are altering registry settings, I'm not coming up with any hits apart from a few unrelated ones. Besides, I do have a GPO in place to increase the port range to xx100 - xx500. However, since RPC isn't functioning normally on many machines on the network, this particular GPO isn't being accepted either.